# A unique rebus+

Tags: visual, lateral-thinking, rebus

I'd call this a rebus+ (complexity, visual components, lateral thinking). The answer is **a letter.**

Short story of the problem:

I was happy, I felt I finally invented something solvable, easy, and good. After telling the solution to my girlfriend, she frowned at me, and said: "This is not solvable, not easy and..not good. Sorry.." ... BUT I accept only opinions from PSE! So let's get started!

[image]

Hint:

> The unique rebus requires a unique hint. I hereby reveal the structure of the problem, let's see how it works in this company of problem solvers. It's virtually a biconceptual (and "games" related) unified context, where abstraction leads to word A and visual (multiple,redundant) clues lead to word B, where B⊆A and the solution is A\B.

Hint2

> The object (a game) and the "type" inside the object refers to word B, the "meaning" (and another game) will lead to word A.  And then solve as per Hint1.

Hint3

> What's the difference between dog and god?

Comment: Could it possibly be rot13(Oernxvat Onq)?

Comment: No, it's not that.

Comment: That looks a lot like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=etch+a+sketch&sxsrf=AOaemvJvNpQGkMOJ4TIrl_tM7omNbzWgfA:1638936898024&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwifm_bcq9P0AhWQN5QKHTKCDHQQ_AUoAXoECAIQAw&biw=1280&bih=757&dpr=0.8).

Comment: threw in a bounty , this needs attention

Comment: @Quark-epoch He might not be online rn. He cant accept an answer because of that

Comment: @IsaacRoanSison no one has given a right answer too :/. None of these seem right, anyways, if the bounty expires, is the rep gone?

Comment: @Quark-epoch You can never get back the rep for a bounty, but you can still award it for any answer, even if it isn't accepted.  I guess we just have to hope someone finds a solution that we can agree to most likely be the intended one.

Comment: @Quark-epoch I believe if you don't manually assign the bounty, I will receive half of the bounty once the 24-hour manual period is over. Source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

Comment: @LOTGP whoops i am sorry i have been inactive, anyways i think your answer best suits it so im sorry i couldnt award the whole fifty , but congrats on the 25 rep

Answer (score 6):

Is it the letter:

> **S?**

Word A:

> The difference between dog and god is that dog is god **backwards**.
>
>  This is possibly a reference to the game [Backwords](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/9475/backwords).

Word B:

> Both the image and the typeface are a reference to the Etch-a-Sketch.
>
>  [image: toy]
>  [image: font]
>
>  This iconic toy is known for drawing on the back of a plastic screen using a stylus and aluminum powder.  Thus, the word being clued could be draw + back = **drawback**.

Applying the instructions from Hint 1:

> [a,a,b,c,d,k,r,s,w]/[a,a,b,c,d,k,r,w] = **s**

Answer (score 4):

Per the hint

> **A** is *palindrome* -- "dog god"
>  **B** is *plate* -- the picture resembles a license plate
>  *t* is the only letter found in *plate* that is not found in *palindrome*
>  the answer is the letter T

Comment: Re what you say the picture resembles - that's very country dependent.

Comment: It's not a license plate, but indeed resembles an object. That is one of the clues.

Comment: The picture resembles an rot13(rgpu-n-fxrgpu).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, maybe I'm taking this too literally, but:

> is it the letter **R**

Explanation:

> The letters on either side of the palindrome cancel each other out except for a sliver of the first "d" which looks like a Latin Rotunda **"Ꝛ"** or the letter **"R"**.

When you say in your first hint:

> B⊆A and the solution is A\B

I suppose you more mean:

> **A-B?** I may be off, and perhaps it's just a mistake in the image, but I cant imagine how you divide a text by a text unless you mean one cancels the other out leaving the remainder, in which case I would say it is more "A-B". And perhaps your title is ironic calling it a "Rebus+" when it's more a "Rebus-", but maybe I'm reading in too much.

Anyway, Interesting puzzle!

Comment: In set theory, both A\B and A-B can be used to indicate the difference of two sets.